# bullet physics - object stabilization after picking

Tags: bulletphysics

Many of the bullet examples inherit from CommonRigidBodyBase. Objects are picked based on btPoint2PointConstraint. 
I have analyzed a SimpleBox example.

When a falling object is picked it starts rotate around a pick point but rotation decreases with time. After some time a picked object should become stable.

In SimpleBox example I have changed a collision shape form (1,1,1) to (2,2,2):

```
btBoxShape* colShape = createBoxShape(btVector3(2,2,2));
```

When I pick falling object (which is bigger than before) more or less at the same high above the ground it rotates much longer around pick point. Why ?

I wonder how can I control the time which is needed to stabilize object after picking. Let's assume that a gravity is fixed (9.8). I have only one idea: assign a bigger mass to the object. Are there any other parameters ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `btPoint2PointConstraint`, I use `btGeneric6DofConstraint` with all angular motion suppressed.

```
m_pickedRigidBody->setActivationState(DISABLE_DEACTIVATION);

btTransform pivot;
pivot.setIdentity();
btVector3 localPivot = m_pickedRigidBody->getCenterOfMassTransform().inverse() * rayCast.point;
pivot.setOrigin(localPivot);

btGeneric6DofConstraint* DOF6 = new btGeneric6DofConstraint(*m_pickedRigidBody, pivot, true);

bool bLimitAngularMotion = true;
if (bLimitAngularMotion) {
    DOF6->setAngularLowerLimit(btVector3(0, 0, 0));
    DOF6->setAngularUpperLimit(btVector3(0, 0, 0));
}

m_dynamicWorld->addConstraint(DOF6, true);

m_pickedConstraint = DOF6;

float cfm = 0.5f;
float erp = 0.5f;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    DOF6->setParam(BT_CONSTRAINT_STOP_CFM, cfm, i);
    DOF6->setParam(BT_CONSTRAINT_STOP_ERP, erp, i);
}
```

Comment: Can you also answer the why-part?  I want to know too.

Comment: The point to point constraint really only tries to keep two points in two different reference frame together as close as possible. So your picked object is just pulled towards your pick point, but its rotation is not affected. That is why the solution above suggests the angular motion suppression. You can also do this manually by setting the angular velocity to zero if something is picked. That is more like what you would expect from "grabbing" it with your hand.